# Convert cross join SQL to LINQ

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this query:

```
Select * From table1, table2 where table1.Name='jack'
```

Can I write it using LINQ?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a cross join?

Answer (score 0):

```
   contextdb.Table1
            .Include(c=>c.Table2)
            .Select(x=> new  {
                 x.table1Name, 
                 x.property1Table1, 
                 .... , 
                 x.Table2
               })
               .where(x=> x.table1Name='jack')
               .ToList()
```

Comment: FYI: you can format code as code by wrapping it in three backticks \`\`\` above and below the code block

Comment: Thank you  @allmhuran

Answer (score 0):

You can write equivalent logic in LINQ:

```
var v =
   from t1 in table1
   from t2 in table2
   where t1.Name == "jack"
   select new { t1, t2 };
```